# Mac App Using "int system(const char *)" method

Tags: macos, bash

I develope a mac app,which uses mac's internal cmd 'zip' to zip, unzip files manually:

```
system([@"cd ~/Desktop\nzip -r file.zip a.jpg" UTF8String]);
```

this will change folder to Desktop, then compress "a.jpg" into "file.zip" archive.
if i use debug mode,it will show a message in console:

```
adding: a.jpg (deflated 1%)
```

Question:
  How can I get the output message in app rather than in console?I want to know if there is any error when someone use release-mode app on his computer?

```
zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r file.zip . -i a.jpg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you would want NSTask. 
Lots of examples online show how to do the  direction of stderr and stdout.